# netbeans, EJB, glassfish, e-commerce tutorial issues

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

I’ve been following the e-commerce tutorial located here: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/intro.html

Code repo of project [here](http://code.google.com/p/nb-ecom-tut/).

I have ran into a few problems that I believe are related:

1: Trying to view the customers’ orders on the Admin page results in:

```
**WARNING**: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB OrderManager, method: public java.util.Map session.OrderManager.getOrderDetails(int)

**WARNING**: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException

**WARNING**: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB OrderedproductFacade, method: public java.util.List session.OrderedproductFacade.findByOrderId(java.lang.Object)

**WARNING**: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of customerOrderId that does not exist in the query string SELECT o FROM Orderedproduct o WHERE o.orderedproductPK.custOrderid = :custOrderid.
```

2: Trying to view details for a particular order in the admin page results in:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[AdminServlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet AdminServlet threw exception
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of customerOrderId that does not exist in the query string SELECT o FROM Orderedproduct o WHERE o.orderedproductPK.custOrderid = :custOrderid.
```

Both problems have the ‘**findByOrderId**’ method in common and I am at a loss as to what is wrong with it.

The offending method is located in the following directory: src/jsf_crud/src/java/session/OrderedProductFacade.java

(I would link it as a hyperlink but spam prevention measures prevent me)

Not sure what the best course of action is, any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query needs a parameter called "custOrderid" and not "customerOrderId"

Either change the query or change the called parameter.

The query in the OrderedProduct class uses "customerOrderId"

http://netbeans.org/projects/samples/sources/samples-source-code/content/samples/javaee/AffableBean/src/java/entity/OrderedProduct.java

Comment: Progress! I now have a much more manageable error that shouldn't take me long to solve  

SEVERE: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'entity.Customer' does not have the property 'customerID'.


edit: fixed, I had a customer.customerID in the admin index page, system works a treat. Thank you.